# Struct Stock and Data File

Tags: c, file, struct, stocks

Here is what I am suppose to do:

1. Create struct stock - name[20], shares, buyprice,currprice, buycost, currcost, profit.
2. Load from keyboard - name, shares, buyprice, currprice, currcost,profit, buycost.
3. Sort on profit from high to low
4. Find total profit for all stocks
5. Print how many stocks made money, lost money, and broke even.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 2
#include<stdlib.h>
struct stock
{
    char name[20];
    int shares;
    float buyp, currp, buycost, currcost, profit;
};
void load(struct stock s[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name:");
        gets(s[i].name);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter shares:");
        scanf("%d", &s[i].shares);
        printf("Enter buyprice");
        scanf("%f", &s[i].buyp);
        printf("Enter current price");
        scanf("%f", &s[i].currp);

        s[i].currcost = s[i].shares * s[i].currp;
        s[i].buycost = s[i].shares * s[i].buyp;
        s[i].profit = s[i].currcost - s[i].buycost;


    }
}

void print(struct stock s[], int n)
{
        int ne,p,z;
        ne = p = z =0;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(s[i].profit<0)
            ne++;
        if (s[i].profit>0)
            p++;
        if(s[i].profit==0)
            z++;
        printf("Amount of stocks made money:%d\n",p);
        printf("Amount of stocks lost money:%d\n",ne);
        printf("Amount of stocks broke even:%d\n",z);
        printf("The current cost is:%f\n",s[i].currcost);
        printf("The profit is:%f\n",s[i].profit);
        printf("The buycost is:%f\n",s[i].buycost);
    }
}
void totprofit(struct stock s[], int n)

{
    int count = 0,  i;
    float totprofit = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        totprofit +=s[i].profit;
        printf("Total profit is:%f\n",totprofit);
        }
    }

void sort(struct stock s[], int n)
{
    int i; int j;
    stock t;
    for (i = 0; i<n - 1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j<n - 1; j++)
            if (s[j].profit<s[j + 1].profit)
            {
                t = s[j]; s[j] = s[j + 1]; s[j + 1] = t;
            }
}

void main()
{
    stock s[size];
    load(s, size);
    print(s,size);
    totprofit(s, size);
    sort(s,size);
    system("pause");
}
```

**My problem is that when it compiles, it works perfectly until it asks for the name again(because the program runs twice).** Why?

```
Enter name:
Apple
Enter shares:
5
Enter buyprice:
3
Enter current price:
4
Enter name:
Enter shares:
3
Enter buyprice:
4
Enter current price:
5
Amount of stocks made money:1
Amount of stocks lost money:0
Amount of stocks broke even:0
The current cost is:20.000000
The profit is:5.000000
The buycost is:15.000000
Amount of stocks made money:2
Amount of stocks lost money:0
Amount of stocks broke even:0
The current cost is:15.000000
The profit is:3.000000
The buycost is:12.000000
Total profit is:5.000000
Total profit is:8.000000
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the function `void totprofit` has the same name as your variable `float totprofit`.

Change at least one of them.

As for step 7, I'm not sure what you are asking.